# Unity iOS local notifications not being scheduled

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I'm building an application for Android and IOS. Local notifications work fine on Android, but when testing them on iOS, they don't show. Also, whenever I call iOSNotificationCenter.GetScheduledNotifications(); I get nothing back. Am I missing something? Could it be an error on Xcode's side?. This is how I schedule notifications:

```
public static void ScheduleNotification(string _title, string _text, DateTime _fireTime, string _channel = "000")
{
    try 
    {
        var timeTrigger = new iOSNotificationCalendarTrigger()
        {
            Year = _fireTime.Year,
            Month = _fireTime.Month,
            Day = _fireTime.Day,
            Hour = _fireTime.Hour,
            Minute = _fireTime.Minute,
            Second = _fireTime.Second,
            
            Repeats = false
        };

        var notification = new iOSNotification()
        {
            Identifier = "",
            Title = _title,
            Body = _text,
            Subtitle = "",
            ShowInForeground = true,
            ForegroundPresentationOption = (PresentationOption.Alert | PresentationOption.Sound),
            CategoryIdentifier = "category_a",
            ThreadIdentifier = "thread1",
            Trigger = timeTrigger,
        };
        iOSNotificationCenter.ScheduleNotification(notification);
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Debug.LogError(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to request notifications permission first. You can do it with coroutine method like this:

```cs
        IEnumerator RequestAuthorization()
        {
            var authorizationOption = AuthorizationOption.Alert | AuthorizationOption.Badge;
            
            using var req = new AuthorizationRequest(authorizationOption, true);
            while (!req.IsFinished)
            {
                yield return null;
            }
            var success = string.IsNullOrEmpty(req.Error) && req.Granted;

            if (success)
            {
                // handle permissions accepted
            }
            else
            {
                // handle permission declined
            }
        }

...
        // call it on your application startup 
        // or whenever you want to ask user for permission. 
        // But before you schedule any permission.
        StartCoroutine(RequestAuthorization()); 
...
```

If I remember everything right, you have to make `AuthorizationRequest` on every application start. Therefore user will see the permission native popup only at the first time.

Comment: Unfortunately, I already ask permission, and that works fine. Notifications still don't show.